# createElement (input) with Id ;with counter ,Id1,Id2,Id3

Tags: javascript, counter, uniqueidentifier, createelement

i trie to generate dynamic Input fields with unique Ids but i stucked:

```
function addTxtBx(){
    var txtBxHolder = document.getElementById('txtBoxHolder');

    var newTxtBx = document.createElement('input');

    newTxtBx.type = 'text';
    var i=1;

    //newTxtBx.id = document.getElementById("txtWaypoint"[i])
    if(i<10){
        newTxtBx.id = "txtWaypoint"+[i];
        i++;
        break;
    }
    txtBoxHolder.appendChild(newTxtBx);

}
```

i tried it with a for() but always got Id='name'9,
i know im an trainee. :)

Comment: Just keep the iterator outside the function -> http://jsfiddle.net/vNdc5/4/

Comment: i tried that issue but it spit always id=txtWaypoint9,id=txtWaypoint9,id=txtWaypoint9,

Answer (score 0):

I think so where you miss to loop it properly.

```
function addTextBox(ops) {
    var no = document.getElementById('id1').value;
    for (var i = 0; i < Number(no); i++) {
        var text = document.createElement('input');
        text.type = "text";
        text.id = "txtWaypoint" + i;  //id created dynamically
        document.getElementById('divsection').appendChild(text);
    }
}
```

[**Try it**](http://jsfiddle.net/AdQsd/1/)

Comment: thx ,i think its a good begin ,actually it only works with 1 starting inputfield,otherwise i got : `document.getElementById(...) is null`
 
at
`var no = document.getElementById('txtWaypoint').value; `